# Bezier Curve always the same length

Tags: html, canvas, bezier

I'm working on a game in HTML5 canvas.

I want is draw an S-shaped cubic bezier curve between two points, but I'm looking for a way to calculate the coordinates of the control points so that the curve itself is always the same length no matter how close those points are, until it reaches the point where the curve becomes a straight line.

Comment: Is it critical that the lines are exactly the same length, or just that it gets to zero when the start and end point get closer?

Comment: what is the degree of the bezier (how many points?) is it cubic? (4 points - start,end and 2 in the middle)

Comment: A quick-and-dirty solution is to formulate it as an optimization problem: Split the curve into a sequence of straight line segments and minimize the difference between the total length of those line segments and the desired constant length, w.r.t. the free control points. You can use algorithms such as gradient descent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent for this. But an analytical solution would be nicer.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you said "until it reaches the point where the curve becomes a straight line", does that happen when the endpoints are closest or as further away from each other as possible?

Comment: What is the objective of the curve? Smooth, visually pleasing or what? If you know that, you can formulate it as a constrained optimization problem, to maximize the objective under the constraint that the length of the curve is constant. If there is temporal continuity, such as in an animation, an iterative solver would work well since it could use the solution from the previous frame as initialization.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem for a game project :)

Answer (score 2):

This is solvable numerically. I assume you have a cubic bezier with 4 control points.
at each step you have the first (P0) and last (P3) points, and you want to calculate P1 and P2 such that the total length is constant.

Adding this constraint removes one degree of freedom so we have 1 left (started with 4, determined the end points (-2) and the constant length is another -1). So you need to decide about that.

The bezier curve is a polynomial defined between 0 and 1, you need to integrate on the square root of the sum of elements (2d?). for a cubic bezier, this means a sqrt of a 6 degree polynomial, which wolfram doesn't know how to solve. But if you have all your other control points known (or known up to a dependency on some other constraint) you can have a save table of precalculated values for that constraint.

Comment: Is it really this simple? If I understand the problem correctly, we have a bezier curve (x(t), y(t)) where x and y are third degree polynomials. Assume they derivatives, dx/dt(t) = P(t) and dy/dt(t) = Q(t), that are second degree polynomials. Then we want to integrate the arc length ds = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)dt = sqrt(P(t)^2 + Q(t)^2)dt. I don't know how hard it is to integrate square-root expressions of fourth degree polynomials but perhaps math software such as Mathematica can do it.

Comment: At first glance, it appears to me that integrating the square root of that quartic is going to be Hard.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really necessary that the curve is a bezier curve? *Fitting two circular arcs whose total length is constant is much easier.* And you will always get an S-shape.

Fitting of two circular arcs:

[image: Fitting two circles]

Let **D** be the euclidean distance between the endpoints. Let **C** be the constant length that we want. I got the following expression for **b** (drawn in the image):

```
b = sqrt(D*sin(C/4)/4 - (D^2)/16)
```

I haven't checked if it is correct so if someone gets something different, leave a comment.

**EDIT:** You should consider the negative solution too that I obtain when solving the equation and check which one is correct.

```
b = -sqrt(D*sin(C/4)/4 - (D^2)/16)
```

Comment: I think the question requested for something else, i.e. when the end points are very close, he wants the S to be WIDEST. as I understand he wants to simulate a fixed length rope between the endpoints, so this solution won't work

Comment: You can improve this method, by drawing half an oval. to draw an oval you can draw a circle and then use non-uniform scaling to make it an oval. However, I think oval perimeter is also non-analytic so we a are back to square one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in SVG that's *close* to correct:
http://phrogz.net/svg/constant-length-bezier.xhtml

[image]

I experimentally determined that when the endpoints are on top of one another the handles should be
*desiredLength* × *cos(30°)*
away from the handles; and (of course) when the end points are at their greatest distance the handles should be on top of one another. Plotting all ideal points looks *sort of* like an ellipse:

[image: Graph showing actual points compared to ellipse]

The blue line is the actual ideal equation, while the red line above is an ellipse approximating the ideal. Using the equation for the ellipse (as my example above does) allows the line to get about 9% too long in the middle.

Here's the relevant JavaScript code:

```
// M is the MoveTo command in SVG (the first point on the path)
// C is the CurveTo command in SVG:
//   C.x is the end point of the path
//   C.x1 is the first control point
//   C.x2 is the second control point
function makeFixedLengthSCurve(path,length){
  var dx   = C.x - M.x, dy = C.y - M.y;
  var len  = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  if (len >= length){
    C.x  = M.x + 100 * Math.cos(angle);
    C.y  = M.y + 100 * Math.sin(angle);
    C.x1 = M.x; C.y1 = M.y;
    C.x2 = C.x; C.y2 = C.y;
  }else{
    // Ellipse of major axis length and minor axis length*cos(30°)
    var a = length, b = length*Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180);
    var handleDistance = Math.sqrt( b*b * ( 1 - len*len / (a*a) ) ); 
    C.x1 = M.x + handleDistance * Math.sin(angle);
    C.y1 = M.y - handleDistance * Math.cos(angle);
    C.x2 = C.x - handleDistance * Math.sin(angle);
    C.y2 = C.y + handleDistance * Math.cos(angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a lookup table could be constructed from the experimentally determined data?

Comment: @Harold True, or a simple piecewise linear approximation. Still, I'm still looking for [the mathematically correct answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85003/equation-for-control-point-distance-for-fixed-length-cubic-bezier-path-with-spe).

Comment: A [noble goal](http://ressalva.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/yak_crop2.png). In the mean time an approximate solution would probably be valuable to the author of the HTML5 canvas cut-the-rope clone. ;)

Comment: Failing a mathematically correct answer, I suppose my answer above could be improved by anticipating the 9% overshoot in the middle and scaling the values based on distance from the middle.